# How to display all matches in re.findall for a pattern which has string and number in python

Tags: python, regex, search, match

I wanted to extract all matches for the following pattern:

```
pattern = 'link_uid=[0-9]'
```

My string looks like:

```
astr = 'this is test link_uid=23500534 and the second test is link_uid=12345'
```

And I am looking for the following output:

```
link_uid=23500534
link_uid=12345
```

And when I do `re.findall('link_uid=[0-9]', astr)` I am getting: `link_uid=2, link_uid=1`

Answer (score 3):

Your input contains multiple digits, match those with:

```
r'link_uid=\d+'
```

Result:

```
>>> re.findall(r'link_uid=\d+', astr)
['link_uid=23500534', 'link_uid=12345']
```

Comment: I just edited the space, you right, but I don't have space in my examples. Is the \s* for space?

Comment: @user89423: Yes, the `\s*` matches 0 or more spaces.